# C# how to add values in ItemFields inside EmbeddedSchemaField of a STUB component

Tags: sdl-tridion, sites-9, c#, metadata, component

I have an embedded schema for a STUB component metadata field which has 4 fields and marked as "Allow Multiple Values", along-with other fields in SDL Tridion. I am using SDL Tridion Web 9.0.

The STUB component metadata is blank initially. I am using a save event handler in SDL Tridion to populate this metadata from External Metadata of ECL component. I am using `EmbeddedSchemaField` to hold initial metadata field for the embedded field, but I am unable to populate the `ItemFields` inside the EmbeddedSchemaField while saving. I am using the following code to initially hold blank field from collection of metadata Fields of my component.

```
_images = ((EmbeddedSchemaField)metadataFields["Images"]);
```

where `metadataFields` is the metadata fields collection.

While trying to add values to the `ItemFields` inside, I am trying to use

```
IList<ItemFields> _imagesFields = _images.Values;
```

but it gives me Count = 0. So I am unable to do anything with this any further. Any suggestions/hints will be very very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EmbeddedSchemaField.Values` is a collection of `ItemFields` objects (one for each value). If you have an optional embedded field, it will initially not have any values, so indeed `EmbeddedSchemaField.Values.Count = 0`

You can add values to the collection, though:

```
Schema embeddedSchema = ((EmbeddedSchemaFieldDefinition)embeddedField.Definition).EmbeddedSchema;
ItemFields embeddedFields = new ItemFields(embeddedSchema);
embeddedField.Values.Add(embeddedFields);
```

Comment: Thanks! But how do I get the embeddedSchema? Sorry may be I sound foolish here but this is what I did:
ItemFields metadataFields = new ItemFields(subject.Metadata, subject.MetadataSchema); where subject is my STUB component. and then I tried to capture the optional Images field, which is the embedded schema field as 
_images = ((EmbeddedSchemaField)metadataFields["Images"]); So how should I get the emdedded schema of this field?

Comment: I have updated the example to make this clear.

Comment: Hello Rick, thanks for updating. However, I have used ```ItemFields``` to get all metadata fields and ```ItemFieldDefinition``` does not contain any definition of ```EmbeddedSchema```. So your example is not working for me. 
This is my code snippet:
```private EmbeddedSchemaField _images;

   //Get metadata XML for stub component first

   ItemFields metadataFields = new ItemFields(subject.Metadata, subject.MetadataSchema);

_images = ((EmbeddedSchemaField)metadataFields["Images"]);```

Can you please advise?

Comment: Updated the example again. :-) I’m sorry, I currently can’t check if the code compiles, but this is the general idea.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rick. It works!!